# How to allow a user to change timezone, but stay on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timezone

Basically, I need the user to be able to change the timezone, but keep them on the same page. The reason for this is, I'm using a jQuery/ajax page loader script, and when I use the form/php I currently have it just goes to the actual php file (the php file works fine). I just need it to stay on the page.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set($_POST['timezones']);
?>

<form action="data4.php" method="post">
<select name="timezones">
  <option>Select your timezone</option>
  <option value="Europe/London">Europe/London</option>
  <option value="America/Mexico_City">Central</option>
  <option value="America/New_York">Eastern</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I do plan on adding more timezones, this was just for demonstration.

If anyone has some useful information/help, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Comment: What are you trying to do here in detail? When setting date_default_timezone_set() in PHP, it's just for that request, what does nothing more than showing the timezones. Maybe you should do it in a cookie, if you try to set it via JS (without page-loading) and use it in your PHP code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<?php
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['timezone'])) {
            if(!isset($_REQUEST['offset'])) {
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var d = new Date()
            var offset= -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
            location.href = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?offset="+offset;
        </script>
<?php
            } else {
                $zonelist = array('Kwajalein' => -12.00, 'Pacific/Midway' => -11.00, 'Pacific/Honolulu' => -10.00, 'America/Anchorage' => -9.00, 'America/Los_Angeles' => -8.00, 'America/Denver' => -7.00, 'America/Tegucigalpa' => -6.00, 'America/New_York' => -5.00, 'America/Caracas' => -4.30, 'America/Halifax' => -4.00, 'America/St_Johns' => -3.30, 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' => -3.00, 'America/Sao_Paulo' => -3.00, 'Atlantic/South_Georgia' => -2.00, 'Atlantic/Azores' => -1.00, 'Europe/Dublin' => 0, 'Europe/Belgrade' => 1.00, 'Europe/Minsk' => 2.00, 'Asia/Kuwait' => 3.00, 'Asia/Tehran' => 3.30, 'Asia/Muscat' => 4.00, 'Asia/Yekaterinburg' => 5.00, 'Asia/Kolkata' => 5.30, 'Asia/Katmandu' => 5.45, 'Asia/Dhaka' => 6.00, 'Asia/Rangoon' => 6.30, 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' => 7.00, 'Asia/Brunei' => 8.00, 'Asia/Seoul' => 9.00, 'Australia/Darwin' => 9.30, 'Australia/Canberra' => 10.00, 'Asia/Magadan' => 11.00, 'Pacific/Fiji' => 12.00, 'Pacific/Tongatapu' => 13.00);
                $index = array_keys($zonelist, $_REQUEST['offset']);
                $_SESSION['timezone'] = $index[0];
            }
        }
        date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['timezone']);
?>

    </head>
    <body>
        Current Time Zone is <?php echo $_SESSION['timezone']; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically how this works is pretty simple, you can have this script be the very first thing your page does because the timezone will stay in the session.

Starting with the session_start(); it will first check to see if there is a timezone variable in the SESSION, if not then it will check the REQUEST for and offset variable. If not, the it will use the JavaScriptand reloads the page with the correct timezone that it detects from the browser by using a $_GET method checks the offset (which will return -12 through +12) and match against the array. Finally it will set the default date_time_zone to the detected JavaScript and your all set. You can have it display the time zone.

Hope that helps

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It works fine for me, but for other users, it's redirecting them to something that doesn't exist. I'm not sure what exactly is going on, I'm very puzzled. It's supposed to be http://www.habbolicious.com/v2/#!/Events, but it's linking them to http://www.habbolicious.com/v2/load_page.php?offset=-6 .

Comment: That is coming from the <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> just change that to the page you wish to load like this:

location.href = "www.habbolicious.com/v2/#!/Events/{page name here}?offset="+offset;

Comment: I tried that, but events.php is it's own file. I'm using an ajax script to include other php files when navigating. It basically removes the .php of the file and includes it within the content. The actual php file works fine when navigating to it, but if I view it on the main site like it's mean to be viewed it doesn't work. It works for me and not other users because I viewed the actual php file then tried it on the main site, and I guess the session had already started so it didn't have to start again.

Comment: This is not a very good approach.  Correlating a time zone name to an offset requires a specific date and time.  That's found here in your `var d = new Date()`, so you're getting the *current* offset at the browser, but then you're correlating it to *fixed* offsets in your *$zonelist*.  So that's assuming that the offset never change - which they DO, since many time zones have daylight saving time.  You're also assuming that there is only one time zone for a given offset, which is also false.  You might want to refer to the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: @Matt - Although you are correct about the DST changes, since the date is being called from the browser it is getting the DST if the computer has updated. Which 99.9% of them do now. As for the array, that was just a quick mock up that I did. DST can be calculated fairly easy, even with PHP as long as you know the timezone.

Comment: @user2974604 - I would be happy to assist you with this, the reason it is taking so long to answer is because I am searching the help section to find out if I can pimp myself out on here. Overall I believe it could be fairly easily be done with what your trying to do. I don't want to give out any contact information until I know for sure that I am allowed to ask for something in return.

Comment: @user2974604 although the method to this madness is pretty simplistic, basically step 1. Check the date and time from the browser. Step 2. Place it in a session variable so it will remain intact when the browser refreshes with the offset in the URL. Step 3. Get the query "offset" from the URL and match it against the list of timezones in the array. Try removing the session_start at the top of the code. There are other ways you can do this... One is to place all of this into a function and call it wherever you need it. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

One way is that - you can fire an ajax request, when changes the timezone, from backend timezone will be changed. But if need to change somewhere time in the same page then need to refresh that section as well with ajax.

add one class in dropdown, name is `change_time_zone_trigger`

```
<select name="timezones" class="change_time_zone_trigger">
<option>Select your timezone</option>
<option value="Europe/London">Europe/London</option>
<option value="America/Mexico_City">Central</option>
<option value="America/New_York">Eastern</option>
</select>
```

Then create a trigger when evner clicks on any timezone.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').delegate('.change_time_zone_trigger', 'change', function(evt) {
    // here put your ajax code that will hit the server when ever any timezone will be changed.

  });

});
```